# How do I call a TSQL function from ado.net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a function defined in SQL Server (that takes a string and a int) how do I call it with ADO.NET?

(If it is 100% same as calling a stored proc, please just say so, as there a lot of examples on calling stored procs about)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only difference is that you must have a special paramter added for the return value

See: [MySqlCommand call function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080940/mysqlcommand-call-function/3081005#3081005)

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
  using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "MyFunction";

    SqlParameter returnValue = command.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return returnValue.Value;
  }
```

Comment: @SašaĆetković The referenced link is MySqlCommand since it was a pre-existing answer, the code snippet in the answer is SQL-Server