# Call SQL Function using ADO .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, stored-procedures, ado.net

I want call function created in SQL Server, which receives two parameters and returns an integer. When I call stored procedure, I use the following code:

```
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME"

    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param1", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(user)))
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param2", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(password)))
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
    table = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(table)
```

In this case I have a table returned by the stored procedure. What changes if I want use a function that returns a scalar value instead of stored procedure?

Comment: Possibly your are looking for [How do I call a TSQL function from ado.net][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145329/how-do-i-call-a-tsql-function-from-ado-net

Comment: @John But I want just retunr scalar value! Why use stored procedure? Are you sure I can't call directly Function?

Comment: @Cuong I tried with your code, but does not return the correct value.

Comment: The error message says: ParameterDirection 'ReturnValue' specified for parameter '@RETURN_VALUE' not &#232; supported. The paramaters with table value support onlyParameterDirection.Input.

Comment: If you have the line `RETURN @RETURN_VALUE` in your SP/Command then my answer should be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call that function directly, only `StoredProcedure`, `Text` (*query*), and `TableDirect` are allowed. Since you are already exposed with stored procedure, why not create a procedure that has the function on it?

In your C# code, you can use the `ExecuteScalar` of your command object

```
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sqlcmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME"
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param1", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(user)))
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param2", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(password)))

Dim obj as Object = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar() 
' obj hold now the value from the stored procedure.
```

Your stored procedure should look like this now,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME
    @param1 VARCHAR(15),
    @param2 VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT function_name(@param1, @param2)
    FROM...
    WHERE....
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a single value, you could call the function using a SELECT query

sql server code

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test
(
  @p1 varchar(10),
  @p2 varchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @p1 + @p2
END
```

vb.net code

```
Using cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
  Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Test(@p1,@p2)", cnn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "1")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "2")

    Try
      cnn.Open()
      Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString)  //returns 12
    Catch ex As Exception
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
  End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the value from the stored procedure as a single row, single column result set use the [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method.

My preferred method is to actually use the return value of the stored procedure, which has been written accordingly with the TSQL `RETURN` statement, and call [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Examples are provided for both on MSDN but for your specific situation,

```
Dim returnValue As SomeValidType

Using connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString))
    SqlCommand command = New SqlCommand() With _
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, _
            CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME" _
        }

    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter() With _
        {
            Name = "@RC", _
            DBType = SomeSQLType, _
            Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue  _ // The important bit
        }
    command.AddWithValue("@param1", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(user))
    command.AddWithValue("@param2", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(password))

    command.Connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    returnValue = CType(command.Parameters["@RC"].Value, SomeValidType)
End Using
```

---

As an aside, you'll note that in .Net 4.5 there are handy asynchronous versions of these functions but I fear that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: SqlCommand command = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection).  In this row, what is queryString?

Comment: @Joseph82, I edited the answer to more closely match your OP.